# select query does not work with parameters using Parameters.AddWithValue

Tags: c#, mysql

The following query in C# doesn't work, but I can't see the problem:

```
string Getquery = "select * from user_tbl where emp_id=@emp_id and birthdate=@birthdate";

cmdR.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_id", userValidate.emp_id);
cmdR.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate", userValidate.birthdate);

OdbcCommand cmdR = new OdbcCommand(Getquery, conn);
OdbcDataReader Reader = cmdR.ExecuteReader();
```

`Reader.HasRows` returns no result but when I query it to my database I got data.

Comment: Any reason you're using ODBC here rather than the MySQL driver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume your code is actually not *quite* as presented, given that it wouldn't currently compile - you're using `cmdR` before you declare it.

First, you're trying to use named parameters, and according to the documentation of [`OdbcCommand.Parameters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters), that isn't supported:

> When `CommandType` is set to `Text`, the .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC does not support passing named parameters to an SQL statement or to a stored procedure called by an `OdbcCommand`. In either of these cases, use the question mark (`?`) placeholder.

Additionally, I would personally avoid using `AddWithValue` anyway - I would use something like:

```
string sql = "select * from user_tbl where emp_id = ? and birthdate = ?";
using (var connection = new OdbcConnection(...))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new OdbcCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@emp_id", OdbcType.Int).Value = userValidate.EmployeeId;
        command.Parameters.Add("@birthdate", OdbcType.Date).Value = userValidate.BirthDate;
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Use the reader here
        }
    }
}
```

This example uses names following .NET naming conventions, and demonstrates properly disposing of resources... as well as fixing the parameter issue.

I do think it's slightly unfortunate that you have to provide a name for the parameter when adding it to the command even though you can't use it in the query, but such is life.

Comment: how do i use (?) in my query?

Comment: Remember in that case it's required to be in the specific order you want to pass it.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
string Getquery = "select * from user_tbl where emp_id=? and birthdate=?";
cmdR.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_id", userValidate.emp_id);
cmdR.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthdate", userValidate.birthdate);
OdbcCommand cmdR = new OdbcCommand(Getquery, conn);
OdbcDataReader Reader = cmdR.ExecuteReader();
while(Reader.Read())
{ 
  //Do something;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I wanted to share my solution for anyone else coming up on this.

I was having issues with the typical method that Jon posted. I have used it before, but for some reason with this new string I had it was not wanting to actually place the parameter correctly and was causing the reader to not work.

I ended up doing something like this instead, since in the end we are just replacing parts of a string.

```
string sql = "select * from user_tbl where emp_id = "+ var1 +" and birthdate = "+ 
var2""
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(sql);
```

This was easier for me to get to work. Be warned though, I am not sure if it has any specific drawbacks when compare to using the command parameter method.

Comment: I believe that adding parameters in this way would leave your code open to some form of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Ahh, thanks! That makes sense. I'll be sure to avoid that now.